# Adjoint method in MODFLOW

Tags: ode, flopy

As far as I have researched, it seems that the adjoint method, which is utilized for calculating sensitivities, is not implemented in MODFLOW 6, whereas it was implemented in MODFLOW 2005.

1. Is this correct?
2. If so, why isn't the adjoint method implemented in MODFLOW 6?

Comment: Is there a difference to gradient computation in backward AD mode? Afaik, calling the gradient components "sensitivities" is more an indication of the intended use and not of the computation itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct that mf6 does not have a baked-in adjoint solution.  However I'm part of a group that is working on an open-source generic adjoint solver for mf6 and we are planning to release it in a couple of months...